# Using control characters in XSLT, like the End Of Transmission character

Tags: xslt

I am using End Of Transmission in XSLT. But is is not working. It is failing with "invalid character reference". Can someone help me with this.

```
<xsl:text>109,LODG3</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>8002,5646</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>8006,STARWD</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#x04;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: That's because it's an [invalid XML character](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets)

Comment: Please layout your code in a readable way, most of it walked of the screen but didn't need to. It also helps in [getting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> `<xsl:text>&#x04;</xsl:text>`

This is [invalid in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets), but is [valid in XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets). Depending on the processor you are using, or more formally, the XML Reader used to build the XDM tree, you will be able to use XML 1.1. For that to work, typically both the stylesheet and the XML source needs an XML 1.1 prolog:

```xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Note that XML 1.1 became a Recommendation in 2006, at the time XSLT 1.0 became a Recommendation (in 1999), XML 1.1 did not yet exist. To use XML 1.1, you will need an [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) or [XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) processor with support for XML 1.1.